# OOP Fundamental - C# Refactoring?

Tags: c#, class, oop, hierarchy

(sorry if the title isn't appropriate, not sure how to properly word the question)

A `User` (a person) owns a `Property` (a house, with a street address, etc).

I am refactoring a project and have the following situation.  I have a class called `Property` and a class called `User`.

Business Rule: A user **has** one or more properties.

So, what makes more sense:

`User.GetProperties()` **or**

`Properties.Get(userId)`

Currently I am accessing the properties via the `User` class.  Not sure if this is the common way of handling this relationship.  What do you guys/gals think?

I'm thinking forward here and the reason for the concern is because I will later have:

`Property.Get(state)`

`Property.Get(zip)`

`Property.Get(city)`

`Property.Get(numberOfBedroom)`

etc...

other ways to get properties and I **know** these will be accessible via the `Property` class.  Right?  (I'm firm on this) so given this, does this change how to access a **User's Properties**?

**Update**

I am not asking how to properly create Classes of, like I said I have two classes.  My question, better stated, is:

Should my web api, for the given scenario (`User` has one or more `Property`[ies]):

`/api/user/properties/{userId} // get all user properties`

or

`api/property/user/{userId} // get all user properties`

because I clearly will implement:

`api/property/zip/{zipCode} // get all properties by zip`

`api/property/state/{state} // get all properties by state`

`api/property/city/{city} // get all properties by city`

etc

So, given the last 3 examples, would you

(a) implement `/api/user/properties/{userId}` while implementing all `api/property/...` for the later 3 cases

or

(b) keep it consistent and query the `User`'s `Property`[ies] from the `api/property/user/...` perspective?

then, after answering this question, I could still have the `User` class with a `GetProperties()` method that returns the `List<Property>`

or

I can have the `Property` class with a `GetByUser(int userId)` method that returns the `List<Property>`

Because in the Real World the `User` has 1 or more `Property` not the other way around. So our basic OOP instinct is to model it as such, but when thinking about the WebApi and a potentially publicly exposed API I think the later is preferred but from the C# (server side in me) getting the `Propert`ies from the `User` is what makes sense but the Front-End developer in me (jQuery, Angular, JavaScript, etc.) wants and fluent API such, the `api/property/user/...` may be logical and I may not think to look on the `api/user/propties/...` (or I may)...

so, which API method would you use and why, and which class model would you use and why.

Thanks.

**Update 2**

(thinking to myself) "the answer may be both" create the api both ways `api/user/properties/...` for OOP correctness and `api/property/user/...` for a fluent api and have both call the same Class method?  right?

Comment: It seems your business rule is more complex: there is a list of property descriptors, and user can have one or more property values for these descriptors. Is it true?

Comment: Off the cuff guess - you're more interested in tracking/identifying properties than you are in tracking/identifying users. It sounds to me like your API should be about Properties, and the various ways to get the collection of Properties you care about, than about Users, or ZIP, or State. In short, I think that api/properties/[some attribute of property/{[attribute value]} would make a relatively clean, easily understandable format.

Comment: Updated, no "A User (a person) owns a Property (a house, with a street address, etc)."

Comment: I've deleted my answer and obviously I'm very disappointed... You can't ask a question with a very very generic text, let people put an effort on solving your issue and 10 hours later change the text so it has nothing to do with the original question: now's something related to REST and other concerns..........

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer my fault, I misreported the question, sorry for the inconvenience.  But thanks for your professional opinion! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2 separate things: your entities (Person, Property) and your business logic. In my opinion you should have the Person and and Property classes, and the Person class will have a collection of Properties, but the business logic should go to a separate component, i.e. PropertyComponent (or just PropertyRepo) that will have the methods GetPropertiesByState, GetPropertiesByUser etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rest should identify resource using resource identifier. In my opinion, api structure should be

```
/api/users/ --> Get all users
/api/users/{userId} --> Ger one user
/api/users/{userId}/properties/ --> Get properties of one user
/api/users/{userId}/properties/{propertyid} --> Get one property of one user
```

to get properties

```
/api/properties/ --> Get all properties
/api/properties/{propertyid} --> Get one properties
/api/properties?filter=(zip:zipCodeValue) --> Get all properties by zip code
/api/properties?filter=(state:stateValue) --> Get all properties by state
```

Useful reference for rest https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm